# Azure VPN randomly stops connecting on Windows 11

Tags: windows, vpn, azure

I use Azure VPN to connect to two different Azure environments at once. Periodically, one or more of these connections will die and leave me unable to reconnect. The "Connect" button in the Windows VPN settings doesn't launch the expected Azure VPN connection window. It just doesn't do anything. This forces me to restart my computer to be able to connect again.

I haven't been able to reproduce the problem on demand so I'm not sure whether the issue is necessarily related to connecting to multiple VPNs at the same time or only on Windows 11.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've come to the conclusion that this is either a bug in the Azure VPN connection manager or Windows. Nonetheless, I found a workaround that doesn't require restarting! Open Task Manager, kill the "Microsoft Connection Manager Monitor" task, and then you should be able to re-connect.

Comment: There is no `Microsoft Connection Manager Monitor` in my Task Manager or anything similar to that. Windows 10.

Comment: @VictorZakharov There should be if you are using Azure VPN. It's under "Background processes".

Comment: 144 background processes, they are sorted alphabetically, I see `Microsoft Application Virtualization...` and `Microsoft Edge`, `Connection Manager` would be in between, but it's not there.